# Is Spring's RemoteFileTemplate.get method synchronous?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Is Spring's [RemoteFileTemplate.get](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/file/remote/RemoteFileTemplate.html#get-java.lang.String-org.springframework.integration.file.remote.InputStreamCallback-) method synchronous?

When testing, it appears to be synchronous. When checking the implementation, it seems to be synchronous, too. And I do understand that there is a reason to use a synchronous callback instead of just returning the `InputStream`.

But why does the documentation say nothing about the callback being synchronous/asynchronous? Can I assume that the callback will stay synchronous in future releases?

The reason behind this is that I want to make sure the call blocks until the callback is executed. In example, I expect the following code leads to the following output:

Code:

```java
remoteFileTemplate.get(filePath, stream -> System.out.println("1"));
System.out.println(2);
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

And I never want the output to be:

```
2
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic there is like this:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = session.readRaw(remotePath)) {
    callback.doWithInputStream(inputStream);
    return session.finalizeRaw();
}
```

to close `InputStream` and release remote resources. The `callback` here is just an end-user hook to accept that stream of remote file data. There is no any multi-threaded issues since the session is not shared.

Of course we can't guarantee that provided `InputStreamCallback` impl is thread-safe. Although when you hand of that `inputStream` to other thread in that callback, it is going to be closed and session released. Therefore your other thread is going to suffer from out-dated `InputStream` reference.

I'm not sure what is your concern about callback since this one is not what the framework does. You provide its impl when you call this `get(String remotePath, InputStreamCallback callback)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My concerns are not about thread-safety, but about blocking. I updated my question. Sorry I did not explain my reasoning that well.

Comment: The code in the `RemoteFileTemplate` is really blocking. If your provided `InputStreamCallback` does some thread shifting, it is already out of Framework control and you are on your own.